# react-native update object using setState

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to `update object` using `setState`? I tried this code:

```
import moment from 'moment';

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      pressedDate:{
      },
    }
  }

updateState = (day) => {
    let updateDay = moment(day.dateString).format(_format);
    //When I console.log updateDay, I get this '2019-06-30' 
    console.log(updateDay,'updateDay')

   //I want to update pressedDate with updateDay which is '2019-06-30' 
    this.setState({
      pressedDate:{
         updateDay : {dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true}
      }
    })
  }
```

I am trying to update my object with `updateDay` but nothing happens when I run this code.

Comment: What makes you think nothing happens? Something definitely happens, you **replace** `this.state.pressedDate` with a new object. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (I realize you're using React Native, but a React example would be close enough to show the problem and let people help you with it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said "nothing happens," but that code clearly **replaces** `this.state.pressedDate` with a new object with just the `updateDay` property.

If you meant to add/update `updateDay` without completely replacing `pressedDate` (that is, if it has other properties), you'd do that by making a copy and then updating the copy. The idiomatic way to do that uses property spread:

```
this.setState(({pressedDate}) => ({
    pressedDate: {
       ...pressedDate,
       updateDay : {dots: [vacation, massage, workout], selected: true}
    }
}));
```

Two key things to note there:

1. It's using the callback version of `setState`. Because [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you **must** use the callback version whenever setting state (an updated `pressedDate`) based on existing state (the rest of `pressedDate` other than `updateDay`).
2. `...pressedDate` spreads out the properties of the current version into the new object being created. Then we add `updateDay`, which will overwrite any previous one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you are right but I have one issue. When I said nothing happens I meant `updateDay` which is `2019-06-30` isn't replaced when I called `setState`. In fact, when I `console.log(this.state.pressedDate)` after I follow your code, it still don't replace `updateDay` with '2019-06-30'.

Comment: @kirimi - That's because [state updates are asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). But updating state *will* make React re-render your component (also asynchronously). If you needed a callback when the state has been updated, you can give a second function to `setState`, [details here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).